# Predicting probability

Tags: python, machine-learning

Trying to use `SVC` from `sklearn` to do a classification problem. Given a bunch of data, and information telling me whether some subject is in a certain class or not, I want to be able to give a probability that a new, unknown subject is in a class.

I only have 2 classes, so the problem is binary.  Here is my code and some of my errors

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf=SVC()

clf=clf.fit(X,Y)


SVC(probability=True)
print clf.predict_proba(W) #Error is here
```

But it returns the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: probability estimates must be enabled to use this method
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1946)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to construct the SVC object with `probability=True`

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf=SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X,Y)
print clf.predict_proba(W) #No error
```

Your code creates a SVC with probability estimates and discards it (as you do not store it in any variable) and use some previous SVC stored in clf (without probability)

Comment: WOW, THANK YOU.

This really means a lot. I have been trying a whole bunch of stuff all day.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Always set the parameters before fit.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf=SVC(probability=True)
clf=clf.fit(X,Y)
print clf.predict_proba(W)
```